# how we can add style tag on a div in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am working in React. Now I want to add some new functionality of dark mode and night mode. I want to add some style on a div but It gives some problems. the code of div style is :

```
<div className="container" style={`{backgroundColor : + ${props.mode === "light" ?"white" : "black"}}`}>
```

now anyone can give the concept that how I can use the style tag for a div.

Answer (score 3):

`style` expects you to pass it an object, not a string:

```
<div 
  className="container"
  style={{
    backgroundColor: props.mode === "light" ? "white" : "black"
  }}
>
```

Comment: It is informative. one more thing I would like to find that how we can change the whole body color because the backgroundColor is just change the backgroundColor of the content. what about the complete screen?

Answer (score 2):

you're close!
Inline CSS in React is written like a javascript object. This means you need double curly braces around the style block, and only the stuff on the right side of the colon needs to be a string.

```
<div 
  className="container" 
  style={{
    backgroundColor: props.mode === 'light' ? 'white' : 'black'
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use object, instead of string

```
const bgColor = props.mode === "light" ? "white" : "black";
<div className="container" style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }}>
```